# Nativescript application-setting module: setString('attribute_name', default value) do not return default value after remove('attribute_name')

Tags: nativescript, application-settings

I noticed this anomaly working with application-settings module on a
**nativescript (8.1.2) /angular** project.

Having this code:

```
import { getString} from '@nativescript/core/application-settings';

remove("attribute_name_string")

let attribute_name_string = getString("attribute_name_string","DEFAULT VALUE")

console.log("Print My Local Atribute = " + attribute_name_string)
```

I was expected the result to be:

```
Print My Local Atribute = DEFAULT VALUE 
but it was
Print My Local Atribute =
```

The same for setNumber

```
import { setNumber} from '@nativescript/core/application-settings';
    
    remove("attribute_name_number")

    let attribute_name_number = getNumber("attribute_name_number", 121)

    console.log("Print My Local Atribute Number = " + attribute_name_number)
```

I was expected the result to be:

```
Print My Local Atribute Number = 121 
but it was
Print My Local Atribute Number = 0
```

Two questions here:

1. Why this strange behaviour (anomaly)?
2. How can I clear my variables and get the default value afterwards ?

Please take in consideration the official documentation:
***A default value can be provided in case there is no existing value.***

```
    /**
     * Gets a value (if existing) for a key as a String Object. 
A default value can be provided in case there is no existing value.
     * @param key The key to check for.
     * @param defaultValue An optional value to be returned in case there is no existing value.
     */
    export function getString(key: string, defaultValue?: string): string;

and

/**
 * Removes a value (if existing) for a key.
 * @param key The key to check for.
 */
export function remove(key: string): void;
```

Comment: have you imported "remove"?

Comment: No, I don't but I'll try and let you know. However is strange I don't get any error (?!)

Comment: I ran your samples (fixing import), which worked as expected.

Comment: I confirm the @Yong solution, thank you very much, that could help lots of people